# Satchmo, Want to change template depending on what product category is selected

Tags: django, satchmo

I have two categories listed in my DB.

I would like to change the template *(templates>product>category.html)* depending on which category was selected. (It's because I want to change the colour scheme and header images per category)

How can I do this? Can I change the template that is being specified in the

```
def category_view(request, slug, parent_slugs='', template='product/category.html'):
```

which is in product.views?

Thanks

---

This is my category_view currently which returns a http500 error and an invalid syntax python django error.

```
def category_view(request, slug, parent_slugs='', template='product/category.html'):
    """Display the category, its child categories, and its products.

    Parameters:
     - slug: slug of category
     - parent_slugs: ignored
    """
    try:
        category =  Category.objects.get_by_site(slug=slug)
        products = list(category.active_products())
        sale = find_best_auto_discount(products)

    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        return bad_or_missing(request, _('The category you have requested does not exist.'))

    child_categories = category.get_all_children()

    ctx = {
        'category': category,
        'child_categories': child_categories,
        'sale' : sale,
        'products' : products,
    }

    if slug == 'healing-products'
        template = 'product/i.html'
    if slug == 'beauty-products'
        template ='product/category_beauty.html'

    index_prerender.send(Product, request=request, context=ctx, category=category, object_list=products)
    return render_to_response(template, context_instance=RequestContext(request, ctx))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the tutorials on the Django site and the other places in the documentation, you will find this handled in a way where it get's pretty easy to use different templates:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def category_view(request, slug, parent_slugs=''):
    if category=='category1':
        return render_to_response('template1',RequestContext(request))
    if category=='category2':
        return render_to_response('template2',RequestContext(request))
```

Passing the template as a function parameter is just satchmos way to be able to pass different templates to the view. But you can override that any time. Have a closer look at the docs here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/views/

Comment: please see my code above. I've tried something similar to what you have suggested but not working for me.

Comment: Would be helpfull to know why. Can you post your error messages?

Comment: if you look at the end of my if statements you'll see I left out the :

Comment: oh. You should consider using an IDE. :))

Comment: Syntax error is caused by missing colon at the end of line in your code after `if slug == 'healing-products'`. You can easy verify syntax of files in the whole tree in the current directory by compiling: `python -m compileall $(pwd)`.